# Handling Python postgres transaction (Psycopg2) across multi threaded environement

Tags: python, multithreading, postgresql, psycopg2

```
import psycopg2
import time
import threading

def initiate():
    conn = psycopg2.connect(host='localhost', user='postgres', password='password', port='5432', database='test')
    conn.set_isolation_level(1)
    conn.autocommit = False
    cursor1 = conn.cursor()
    cursor2 = conn.cursor()
    cursor3 = conn.cursor()
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=test1, args=(cursor1, conn))
    t2 = threading.Thread(target=test2, args=(cursor2, conn))
    t3 = threading.Thread(target=test3, args=(cursor3, conn))
    t1.start()
    t2.start()
    t3.start()


def test1(cursor, conn):
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO test_sch.tb_for_test1(col_for_t12, col_for_t13, col_for_t14) VALUES ('test_col1', 'test_col1', 1)")
    time.sleep(10)  
    conn.commit()
    cursor.close()
    print("completed test1")

def test2(cursor, conn):
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO test_sch.tb_for_test1(col_for_t12, col_for_t13, col_for_t14) VALUES ('test_col2', 'test_col2', 2)")
    time.sleep(5)
    conn.commit()
    cursor.close()
    print("completed test2")

def test3(cursor, conn):
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO test_sch.tb_for_test1(col_for_t12, col_for_t13, col_for_t14) VALUES ('test_col3', 'test_col3', 3)")
    time.sleep(15)
    conn.commit()
    cursor.close()
    print("completed test3")

initiate()
```

In the above code I have tried to insert three records to database using three different threads running three different methods. When method test2 gets completed it is committing all three records instead waiting for transaction at method test1 and test3. I can understand that psycopg2 transaction is per connection and not per cursor. So any suggestions on how it can be moved to per cursor basis ?. One of my limitation is not to open too many connections

Comment: Did you had a look at the connection pools: http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/pool.html ?

Comment: "One of my limitation is not to open too many connections" Is 3 really too many?